# Meld tool on Ubuntu how to view 2 screens during gitmerge

Tags: git, meld

I have installed Meld tool on Ubuntu and want to use during conflict resolution with gitmerge command.

The problem I'm facing is that it shows 3 windows and it is quite confusing compared to 2 windows.

Any suggestion how to fix this ?

Comment: I don't use Meld (or any of the merge tools really, I just edit the files directly) so I can't answer about how to do that; but I can tell you *why not* to do that: the reason you are getting a merge conflict at all is that there are three files involved. One of the files is the *base* version, that both `--ours` and `--theirs` changed. The second file is `--ours` (what we did to the file). The third file is `--theirs`, i.e., what they did to the file. If you see only two of the three, you're missing some key information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git config merge.conflictstyle merge
```

This should set the conflict resolution style to 2-file `merge` instead of 3-file `diff3` which is what you're seeing.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-mergeconflictStyle

Comment: `merge.conflictStyle` sets how the merge conflicts are presented in the work-tree file, not how merge conflicts are presented in a merge tool when running `git mergetool`.

Comment: Isn't the mergetool just a wrapper over the work-tree file? It's been a while since I used meld, but I believe it respects the setting.

Comment: No, `git mergetool` extracts the three files from the index to feed to the tool (though it also saves the existing work-tree file in case the tool itself fails). Meanwhile the OP is concerned with windows opened on files, rather than contents of one particular file. The default `merge.conflictStyle` *is* `merge`, too, though I personally think this is backwards (and of course it's possible he copied some config that changes it).